# How to execute home directory shell script file in php

Tags: linux, unix, php, php5

How to execute /home/scripts/test.sh file in php

Previously i have placed 'test.sh' file in the /usr/bin and calling in my php file like this

```
exec('test.sh ' . escapeshellarg($testString));
```

But for security reasons i moved .sh file to /home/scripts directory and in my php i am calling like this

```
exec('/home/scripts/test.sh ' . escapeshellarg($testString));
```

But it is not working now.

Please suggest me how to achieve this.

Comment: What are the permissions on the /home/scripts dir, the shell script, and what user:group is running php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of [`return_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and display the value of `output` - this will probably tell you that you have the wrong permissions set on either /home, /home/scripts or on /home/scripts/test.sh.

Comment: i forgot about giving permission to that file just i copied from local system to there, after giving execute permissions it worked. Thanks a lot....